# How to prove$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\sin^{m}x\cdot \cos^{m}x=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}2^{-m} \cos^{m}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\sin^{m}x  \cos^{m}x=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}2^{-m} \cos^{m}x dx$

I tried integration by parts but got nowhere.
 Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^m x \cos^m x = 2^{-m} \int_0^{\pi/2}(2 \sin x \cos x )^mdx = 2^{-m} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^m (2x) dx$$
Making substitution $2x = y$ gives 
$$2^{-(m+1)} \int_0^{\pi} \sin ^m y dy \overset{(1)}{=} 2^{-(m+1)} 2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^m y dy$$
Changing $y\to \pi/2-y$ gives the required result.
$$2^{-m}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^m (\pi/2-y) dy = 2^{-m} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^m(x) dx$$
$(1)$: becuase $\sin x$ in $[0, \pi]$ is symmetric at $x=\pi/2$

Comment: Think there is a way to derive it from beta and gamma functions?

Comment: @TylerHG do you mean to evaluate the whole integral?

Comment: Not really. I know that it can be evaluated with beta functions. But was wondering if you could change the integral into the new form suggested by the OP using beta and gamma funcs.

Answer (score 5):

$$\sin^mx\cos^mx=\frac{\sin^m(2x)}{2^m}$$

Set $\displaystyle2x=y\implies x=\frac\pi2\implies y=\pi$

Now $$\int_0^\pi\cdots (dy)=\int_0^\frac\pi2\cdots (dy)+\int_\frac\pi2^\pi\cdots (dy)$$

Set $\displaystyle z=y-\frac\pi2$

Finally use $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$ to convert the integrand sine to cosine

Comment: @SantoshLinkha, May I request you to be a more patient in rectifying my answer?

Comment: sure, I just edited the latex ... sorry if it was bad.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha, Actually I was going to put the answer in the current version when I found your quick edit

Comment: lol ... sorry again :) it would have worked anyway.